# Plot ROC curve in Matlab

Tags: matlab, roc

I need to plot a ROC curve in matlab. I have two arrays, one containing the true positive rate and one containing the false positive rate. I've tried both `plotroc` and `perfcurve` with the two arrays as input, but it doesn't seems to work. There is another way for plotting ROC curve with the data I have?

**EDIT**
I'm posting an image in order to answer to Tasos Papastylianou:

[image]

simply plotting the two array it does not really seems a ROC curve :S

**EDIT2**
Upload the image with the array inverted, still not looking like a ROC!
[image]

**EDIT3**
Image showing the plot of my ROC curve, normalized in [0,1]
[[image]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjDqd.png)

Comment: a ROC curve is literally FP vs TP. Why not just use the normal plot command?

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Hi, I've tried but I obtain something really far from a ROC curve. I edited the post so you can see what  happens with the simple plot!

Comment: are you sure you're not plotting TP vs FP? I'd expect the axes to be the other way round given those values

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou yes you are right, but it still strange, doesn't it?

Comment: you mean the shape? Nah. You don't always get the textbook-looking smooth curve. It depends on the number of validations, the way the threshold affects the classification, etc

Comment: plus, your axes don't start from zero. Normalize your axes from 0 to 1 and the plot will make a bit more sense

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou I thought the curve has to be "a curve". I edited the question adding an image of my plot normalized in [0,1]. Do you think it's fine? I'm thinking of add more experiments data in order to give a good shape to the curve. In your opinion, is it worth? Thanks a lot for your answers!

Comment: No problem. Yes, do. I'm sure if you add more validation runs, particularly for more "extreme" thresholds ((i.e. useless ones, which either completely accept or reject the class) it will look even more like you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought I'd post a proper answer with a nice ROC curve example, demonstrating the stuff we discussed in the comments:

```
%% Create datasets

[X,Y] = ndgrid(1:100,1:100);

% Ground Truth image
Circle= zeros(100); Circle((X-50).^2 + (Y-50).^2 - 500 <= 0) = 1;

% Test image (parameterised by threshold)
pkg load statistics % if using octave - needed for 'mvnpdf'
pkg load image      % if using octave - needed for 'mat2gray'
Gaussian = mvnpdf([X(:), Y(:)], [45, 45], [500,0;0,500]);
Gaussian = reshape(Gaussian, size(X));
Gaussian = mat2gray(Gaussian);

%% Generate ROC curve for a range of thresholds
ThresholdRange = 0 : 0.025 : 1;
TPs = zeros(size(ThresholdRange));
FPs = zeros(size(ThresholdRange));
Ind = 0;
for Threshold = ThresholdRange 
  Ind = Ind + 1;
  TP = Circle .* (Gaussian > Threshold);
  T  = Circle;
  TPR = sum(TP(:)) / sum(T(:));
  TPs(Ind) = TPR;

  FP = (1 - Circle) .* (Gaussian > Threshold);
  N  = (1 - Circle);
  FPR = sum(FP(:)) / sum(N(:));
  FPs(Ind) = FPR;
end

%% Plotski curvski
plot(FPs, TPs, 'linewidth', 3, 'marker', 'o', 'markersize',10,'markeredgecolor', 'k', 'markerfacecolor', 'g');
hold on; 
plot(ThresholdRange, ThresholdRange, 'r-.', 'linewidth', 3);
axis([0,1,0,1]);
title('Les Curves du ROC! Ooh-la-la!', 'fontsize', 16);
xlabel('Le Rate des Positifs Falses! Oh mon dieu!', 'fontsize', 14);
ylabel('Le Rate des Positifs Vrais! Magnifique!', 'fontsize', 14);
grid on;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I resolved thanks to the comments provided by @TasosPapastylianou. For getting better results in plotting, I sort the two array on the x-axis (or the False Positive Rates). Thanks again to @TasosPapastylianou !!!